# Noms composés de deux verbes

Tags: noms

**Un laissez-passer et un laisser-aller.**

Quelle logique dicte la construction de noms composés de deux verbes ?

Par exemple, pourquoi la différence que l'on rencontre ici ? (à savoir 2e personne plus infinitif dans le premier cas et infinitif plus infinitif dans le second)

Comment: Sans avoir été chercher, voici mon hypothèse: un *laissez-passer* est un document qui donne un ordre ("laissez passer cette personne"), il est donc assez logique de mettre un impératif. Un *laisser-aller* n'est pas un ordre mais un état général: on se "laisse aller"; l'infinitif est alors logique.

Comment: Merci ! Voici un commentaire qui mérite de prendre la forme de réponse:-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La plupart des mots composés de deux formes verbales utilisent l'infinitif qui est la forme nominale du verbe :

- copier-coller
- faire-valoir
- laisser-aller
- ouï-dire (anciennement ouïr-dire)
- savoir-faire
- savoir-vivre

Comme l'a indiqué Greg dans son commentaire, *laissez-passer* est à l'impératif car il s'agit de la retranscription d'un ordre. On rencontre aussi l'impératif dans le mot composé  *cessez-le-feu*. Le subjonctif est utilisé dans *sauve-qui-peut* et l'indicatif dans l'adverbe *peut-être*.

Il existe aussi des formes au mode moins identifiable comme :

- coupe-coupe
- passe-passe
- pèle-mêle
- pousse-pousse

Note: dans *garde-manger*, *manger* est un substantif.

Comment: Un mot composé drôle avec un verbe à l'impératif, popularisé par une série humoristique: le *fourres-y-tout* (un plat fait rapidement en mélangeant les restes des derniers jours).

Comment: @Greg, oui, le *fourzitou* ;-)

Comment: Il faudrait que l'Académie se penche sur la question: *fourres-y-tout* ou *fourzitou* ?